# Facebook get full name by ID without acces token

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-graph-api, metadata

**Is is possible to get someones name (full name) only by his userID? (without access token)**

https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/?fields=name
The API indicates that an access token is required.

But if you visit a Facebook profile manually you will get their name:
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=USERID

For this, no further verification is required and anyone can see it, isn't it possible for me to get a name from that page? (for example, the full name is in the page title, can I get it from there?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"(for example, the full name is in the page title, maybe i can get it from there)"_ - scraping Facebook is not allowed. What would you need this for anyway?

Comment: You can use your own `access_token` for the url `https://graph.facebook.com/[user_id]?fields=name` to get full name.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you cannot access Facebook without authenticating. **This is not possible**.

> But if you visit a Facebook profile manually you will get the name:
>   https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=USERID

You can get some people profiles by above URL, only when you are logged into Facebook. Did you try to access it without login to Facebook?

Comment: Yes, you can acces the website without logging in to Facebook, and the website gives you the full name of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Answer your question: 
**Is is possible to get someones name (full name) only by his userID? (without access token)**

No, you can't.

How about using app access token? An app access token never experied.

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/?fields=name&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN